# Which JavaScript would have better performance?

Tags: javascript

```
(function (window, $, undefined) {

    "use strict";


    var methods     = {};
    var thingOnPage = $('.class');

    methods.init = function () {

    };

    methods.1 = function() {

    };

    methods.2= function() {

    };

    methods.3= function() {

    };

    if (thingOnPage.length > 0) {
        methods.init();
    }

}(window, jQuery));
```

This gets compiled and included on every page, but the init method will only be called if there is a specific class on the page.

My question is, would I be able to make this more efficient if the conditional statement wrapped the declaration of all the methods?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think a conditional statement can help in your case.

Comment: I don't think it would make too much difference, however you should put it in a jsperf and see what happens.

Comment: Ill give it a go thanks.

Comment: I doubt it'd make a big difference if any at all, depending on the size of the entire code block ofc. one other thing i notised with your code, even though it wont really make a big difference either.. var thingOnPage = $('.class');
if (thingOnPage.length > 0) {
        methods.init();
    }
can be turned into something like
if ($('.class').length > 0) methods.init();
to remove a variable that only seems to get used once anyways

Comment: If you're using jQuery, then you can't be all that serious about performance.

Comment: I was thinking of the [analogy by Eric Lippert on performance rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) ;)

Comment: ...that said, if you're asking if not doing something is faster than doing something, then yes, it's generally pretty safe to assume that not doing it will be faster.

Comment: I ran a few informal benchmarks, and putting the function declarations inside the `if` was pretty consistently 20-25% faster when the `if` evaluated to `false` than when it evaluated to `true`. The difference in execution time was pretty consistently around 0.020 milliseconds, but your best bet would be to benchmark with actual code.

Comment: Also, in response to @squint 's comment - switching from `$(".class").length` to `document.getElementsByClassName("class").length` offers a substantially larger performance benefit - around 0.5 milliseconds in my informal benchmarks - 25 times the benefit of putting the funciton declarations inside the `if`, and you'd get that performance benefit on every page load, as opposed to just on page loads where the el.length was greater than 0.

Comment: @Squint - I was going off the assumption that moving an if statement around would be slightly faster than removing jquery from a site, but to be honest I was more interested in this for curiosity's sake.

Comment: Thanks for answers everyone. very useful